# Flurry + Mono Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, flurry

I am interested in integrating Flurry into my Mono for Android app. To do so, I followed the guide found [Here](http://blog.martinlegris.com/2012/11/14/flurry-api-in-mono-for-android/). Basically I created an android class library, then added the flurry 3.2.1 .jar file to the project (not inside the resources folder) and set its build action as AndroidJavaLibrary. Next I pasted the FlurryClient.cs file(found in the link) and referenced the whole project in my app. All is well except that my flurry dashboard is not reporting any activity (0 sessions), even after a whole week of testing, while my windows phone version of the app is reporting fine. So it seems that no events are being sent to Flurry for some reason.

In addition, during app start-up, the output windows in Visual Studio prints the following line:

**E/FlurryDataSender(14460): --onServerError xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx**

*(xxxxxxx replaces actual number sequence)*

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you found the reason? I have the same issue.

Comment: No, I contacted Flurry support but they never replied. In the end I just released the app without analytic services. If you ever solve it, please let me know.

Comment: What did you try? My code: var client = new FlurryClient ("My key");
            client.SetLogEnabled (true);
            client.OnStartActivity (this);
            client.LogEvent ("test + " + DateTime.Now);

Comment: I successfully received basic (non-timed) events. FlurryClient make a log event: `[FlurryDataSender] --onReport f7b6c49b-3c1b-4aa9-bfd0-1d015d65a67a sent. HTTP response: 200 : OK`

Comment: What did you change to fix this problem? my code is identical to yours except I do not have the `client.SetLogEnabled (true);` line.

Comment: I subclass all activities, add `client.OnStartActivity (this)` to `onStart()` method and `client.OnStopActivity (this)` to `onStop()` method.

Comment: My app has only one activity, and I do have `client.OnStartActivity (this)` and `client.OnStopActivity (this)` inside `onStart()` and `onStop()`, so it is still no different from yours...